# Json to Pandas/Excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to export all data from a Json to Excel workbook. The Json is very complex. The following is the structure:

```
"section": [
            {
                "name": "Sch1",
                "subsection": [
                    {
                        "Sch1": {
                            "pg1_non_calendar_end_date": [
                                {
                                    "column1": "AA"
                                }
                            ],
                            "pg1_document_status_final": [
                                {
                                    "column2": "XX"
                                }
                            ],....
                           }
```

This continues for thousands of values.

Expected Output:

[image]

My system is Windows 10 with Python 3. I am using Pandas to try to get the data in the way I want. But the result is coming like:

[image]

I am using the following o

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(books[3]['subsection'][0])
df2 = (
    df2["Sch1"]
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .merge(df2, left_index = True, right_index = True)
)
o = 'output.xslx'
df2[0].to_excel(o, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has [many ways to read JSON files](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) into dataframes. For your use case, iterate over each sheet and read the json files using the following option:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
input_data = json.load("input.json")
sheets = list() # this would be generated from your original json file
for section in input_data["section"]:
    for subsection in section["subsection"]:
        sheet = json.dumps(subsection)
        sheet_df = pd.read_json(sheet, orient="records")
        sheet_df.to_excel("output.xslx", sheet_name="Your_Sheet_Name")
```

Alternatively you can look into the `pd.from_records` method for properly loading your data.